# Getting the details of application versions of all vz nodes through command line

Tags: linux, grep, bash-scripting, awk, openvz

### Finding application details of all the openvz containers

Needed to find the versions of applications(like cpanel, apache,php, mysql, ruby and rails)

Answer (score 0):

The following script was used to find the details

> *for i in `vzlist -a|  grep [0-9]`; do echo "----------------------------------------------" &&  vzctl exec $i hostname && vzctl exec $i /usr/local/cpanel/cpanel -V && vzctl exec $i httpd -v | grep version |awk '{print $3}' && vzctl exec $i mysql --version | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 }' && vzctl exec $i php -v | awk 'NR==1'| gawk '{print $1, $2}'  && vzctl exec $i ruby -v | gawk '{print $1, $2}' && vzctl exec $i rails -v; done;*